# How to use TabBarController inside another TabBarController using storyboard reference

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

After successful login user is taken to a tabViewController having 5 different tabs. All 5 tabs in the tabviewcontroller are storyboard references. I am getting tab bar icon at the bottom for 4 tabs but for the 5th tab icon is not showing but on touching the vacant space I can move to the 5th tab. For the fifth tab in the tabViewController I am using another tabViewController having 4 different tabs. Please help me so that the icon is visible.

[image: Slider Image 1]

I have tried to set the icon using this line of code. But this is also not working.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[4].image = UIImage(named: "Icon-1")
```

Comment: try to add "container" controller for your second Tabbar

Comment: Can you please guide me for the same?
@AlexandrKolesnik